# How can I add my custom iOS map application in "Open direction in" list in other apps?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I 've developed an iOS map and navigation application, like Waze. I want my app to be in "Open in" list in other application to show the route between two points. For example when you share a location with messaging app like Telegram, WhatsApp, ... a user can choose between Maps, Google Maps, Waze, Uber, ...to navigate to a specific location and the selected app will be launched. How can I add my application to the list?

Comment: Your app needs to [register as a routing app](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html)

Comment: @Paulw11Thank you very much.